# Why modern curl versions cut off the #anchor part of the URL?

Tags: http, url, curl, libcurl

I have observed a curious behaviour between different curl versions.

In CentOS 6 with curl 7.19.7 if I do `curl 'localhost:9999/foo#bar'` (nc listening on 9999) I get:

```
GET /foo#bar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Host: localhost:9999
Accept: */*
```

but if I do the same curl on a modern system (Debian 8) with curl 7.38.0 I get:

```
GET /foo HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
Host: localhost:9999
Accept: */*
```

Note the URL is different: `/foo#bar` (7.19.7) versus `/foo` (7.38.0)

I understand that the right behaviour is removing the `#anchor` part, given is the one the newer version of curl implements. However, I don't understand the reason of that change... Any hint about such reason or a reference to look (e.g. RFC) for it, please?

I have tried to find information in [the curl changelog](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html) but it is too verbose and I haven't found the change and/or rationale behind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix is described in https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_20_0:

"fragment part of URLs are no longer sent to the server"

The rational is that, well, the fragment identifier is not to be sent in HTTP requests. See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.5.1.p.2:

"The target URI excludes the reference's fragment component, if any, since fragment identifiers are reserved for client-side processing ([RFC3986], Section 3.5)."

Comment: Thank for so precise answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to escape this code and all other special symbols of URI:

`curl 'localhost:9999/foo%23bar'`

This seems works with my curl 7.47.0.

Comment: That's a different URL.